# Passing a non-static method or std::function<void(...)> as a void (*) argument

Tags: c++, casting, arguments, std

I'm trying to define a function/method (`void MyClass::myDispatcher(int, int, void *)` or `std::function<void(int, int, void *)> myDispatcher`) which would be a member of a host class.

However, I also need to pass this function to through an external library which takes as argument: `void (*dispatcher) (int, int, void *)`.

**Is there a way I can convert a non-static function to the required `void (*)(int, int, void *)` type ?**

My first attempt with the candidate `void MyClass::myDispatcher(int, int, void *)` was using the `std::bind()` in order to bind `MyClass::myDispatcher` with `this`. Although I could not convert the return type of `std::bind` to match the `void (*)`.

The second attempt was done using `std::function<void(int, int, void *)> myDispatcher` for which I tried to use the `reinterpret_cast<void (*)(int, int, void *)>(&myDispatcher)` to fit in the requested argument. It did compile but I ultimatly ended up in a segfault within the external library.

I could summarized my two attempts with this example:

```cpp
class MyClass{
  MyClass() = default;
  
  void myDispatcher(int, int, void *){
    // do something
  }

  void init(){
    myFct = [this](int, int, void*){
      // do something
    };
    
    external_function(reinterpret_cast<void (*)(int, int, void *)>(&myFct));

    // or the non-compiling
    // external_function(std::bind(&MyClass::myDispatcher, this));
  }

private:
  std::function<void(int, int, void*)> myFct;

};
```

### **Edit:**

As some of you pointed out: this C-style `external_function` has an extra `void *` argumement which is passed as the last arg to the provided function!

To summarise: there is no way to do such a thing since there is a fundamental difference between a function pointer and non-static member functions. However, C-style library usually provides a workaround which performs a callback to the provided static function:

```cpp
void external_function(void (*dispatcher) (int, int, void *), void* info){
  // a bunch of instructions (meaningless for this example)
  
  int a,b;

  dispatcher(a,b,info);
}
```

Once we know that, one can cast back the `info` pointer to the class we want.

Comment: Traditional way with c-function to allow to have custom data is to have as last parameter a `void* userData`, which seems the case of your external library `void (*dispatcher) (int, int, void *)`. If so your method would be `void MyClass::myDispatcher(int, int);` and you pass `[](int i, int j, void* userData){ reinterpret_cast<MyClass*>(userData)->myDispatch(i, j); }` for the external library.

Comment: IMO you have striped your question from vital information. Please provide detail about C-API you are trying to use. As Jarod42 points out there is some standard in C to pass callbacks similar to lambda and most probably this is your case. If you will provide this detail we can give you better answer how to do this bridge to C-API properly.

Comment: Indeed, by looking at the source code of the C-API there is an extra `void*` arg (I used to ignore) which passes its value to the last argument of the provided function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, this is not possible since there is no way to meaningfully construct a plain function pointer from a (non static) method, a closure, or a `std::function` object.

Roughly speaking, each of the constructs above are logically formed by two parts: some fixed code (a pointer to a fixed, statically known function), and variable data (the object at hand, or the captures for a closure). We can not simply throw away the second part.

That being said, I would recommend to check if the library will call the `dispatcher` passing a user-defined pointer for its `void *` argument. It's somewhat common to see C style library functions like

```
void register_callback(void (*dispatcher)(int,int,void *), void *user_data);
```

This is a trick to allow to simulate closures in C, passing the two "parts" of the closure separately.

If that's the case, instead of

```
// not working, just for example
std::function<void(int, int)> f;
register_callback(f);
```

You can write

```
// Make sure f will live long enough.
// I'm using new to stress the point, but you can use anything
// else provided that the pointer will be valid when f is
// called.
std::function<void(int, int)> *pf = new ...;
register_callback(call_the_function, pf);
```

provided you have defined

```
// fixed function, independent from the std::function object
void call_the_function(int x, int y, void *p) {
   std::function<void(int,int)> *pf =
      (std::function<void(int,int)>*) p;
   (*pf)(x,y);
}
```

If you used `new` to keep the pointer valid long enough, remember to `delete` it when the callback is no longer needed.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the solution! As you suggested the `void *` is actually meant to be used to provide user data to the function, and by looking at the source code of the C function there is an actual extra `void *` arg in which I provided a `nullptr`!

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can convert a non-static function to the required void (*)(int, int, void *) type ?

No, there isn't. A function pointer cannot point to non-static member functions, nor to function wrapper objects.

What you can do, is point to a normal function that in turn calls the member function. The challenge is getting the instance into that function. Most C callback API allow passing user defined data into the callback in form of a pointer to void, in which case this isn't a problem. If there is no such option, then you can only use a globally accessible instance, or an instance that is created within the callback.

You will need to read the documentation of the API to find if and how passing user data is possible. There is a `void*` parameter in the callback, which hints that it may be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't get a `void (*)(int, int, void *)` from a non-static member function. Non-static member function are fundametally different from free functions: You need an object to call the method.

However, in your code you are already using `std::function` and `std::function` has a constructor to convert a `void (Foo::*)(int, int,void*)` to a `std::function<void(Foo*,int,int,void*)>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I see your point. 

About the `std::function` you mean that there is a way I could use this conversion to make my `void (*)(...)`?

Comment: @nadrino note the additional `Foo*` argument. The function needs the instance somehow, `std::function` allows to pass it as first argument. If you need member functions of different classes then this won't help much though

Answer (score 1):

The external library expects a C style function pointer. I't won't accept C++ callable objects (e.g. std::function or std::bind). You have to wrap the C++ callable objects inside a plain function with the required signature. Something like this:

```
void dispatcher(int theInt1, int theInt2, void *theData) {
   theInstanceOfMyClass.myDispatcher(theInt1, theInt2, data);
}
```

You might want to pass the address of your C++ instance as the third argument, e.g.:

```
void dispatcher(int theInt1, int theInt2, void *theData) {
   static_cast<MyClass *>(theData)->myDispatcher(theInt1, theInt2, data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `theInstanceOfMyClass` would be a global object then?

Comment: @nadrino I ammended my answer to suggest that you pass the address of your instance as the void pointer.

Comment: Sorry the `void *` has nothing to do with `MyClass` itself! It's an arg required by the function!

Comment: @nadrino I understand that. But when you install the callback handler, you can probably tell the library what to pass as the void pointer. e.g.: LibInstallCallback(dispatcher, &theInstanceOfMyClass).